# Post request response is not saved in afnetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am having problems in saving a response coming from a POST request. 
Based on AFnetworking [documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.html) and NSScreencast [tutorial](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/91-afnetworking-2-0) I created my own subclass of AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, but I am not sure why the response is not saved.

How do I know, the response is not saved?
Because  `there is an error:(null)` message in console and the my method does not perform segue.

I know that I am getting the values, because of the breakpoint that I put NSURLSessionDataTask

But I do not know why the values are not saved and I am getting an error message. I appreciate any help.

The APIClient/Manager

AuthAPIManager.h

```
#import "AFHTTPSessionManager.h"

    @interface AuthAPIManager : AFHTTPSessionManager
    +(AuthAPIManager *)sharedManager;
    -(NSURLSessionDataTask *)initializeLogin:(NSString *)username completion:(void(^)(NSDictionary *results, NSError *error))completion;

    //for login
    @property (nonatomic,readonly,retain)NSString *StoreIdentifierForVendor;
    @property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *devicetype;
    @end
```

AuthAPIManager.m

```
#import "AuthAPIManager.h"
#import "LoginInfo.h"
#import "CredentialStore.h"
static AuthAPIManager *sharedManager =nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
@implementation AuthAPIManager

+(AuthAPIManager *)sharedManager
{
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            sharedManager = [[AuthAPIManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]];
            sharedManager.responseSerializer=[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
            sharedManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
        });

    return sharedManager;
}

-(id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}
-(NSURLSessionDataTask *)initializeLogin:(NSString *)username completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary *, NSError *))completion
{
    _devicetype = @"ios";
    _StoreIdentifierForVendor = [[[UIDevice currentDevice]identifierForVendor]UUIDString];

    id loginParameters =@{@"AccountId":username,
                          @"DeviceType":_devicetype
                          };




    NSURLSessionDataTask *task =[self POST:@"/Accn" parameters:loginParameters
                                   success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
                                   {
                                       NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
                                       if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                                         LoginInfo *loginInfo =[[LoginInfo alloc]initWithDictionary:responseObject];
                                           CredentialStore *credStore =[CredentialStore sharedStore];
                                           credStore.loginInfo =loginInfo;
                                           completion(responseObject,nil);
                                           loginInfo = responseObject;



                                       } else {
                                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                               completion(nil, nil);
                                           });
                                           NSLog(@"Received: %@", responseObject);
                                           NSLog(@"Received HTTP %d", httpResponse.statusCode);
                                       }

                                   } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                           completion(nil, error);
                                       });
                                   }];
    return task;
}
@end
```

And this is how I am calling my method in my view controller

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
 [_usernameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [SVProgressHUD show];
 NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[AuthAPIManager sharedManager] initializeLogin:self.usernameTextField.text completion:^(NSDictionary *results, NSError *error)
                                  {
                                      if (results) {
                                          LoginInfo *loginInfo = [[LoginInfo alloc]initWithDictionary:results];
                                          CredentialStore *credStore =[ CredentialStore sharedStore];
                                          credStore.loginInfo =loginInfo;
                                          [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"welcomeViewSegue" sender:self];
                                      }

                                      else
                                      {
                                          NSLog(@"there is an error:%@",error);
                                      }
                                  }];
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your success block is being called, but your status code is not 200.

You are calling your completion block like this:

```
completion(nil, nil);
```

So this code:

```
if (results) {
   [snip]
}

else
{
    NSLog(@"there is an error:%@",error);
}
```

is passed a `nil` results object.

1. Set a breakpoint on `if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200)` and inspect `httpResponse` in your debugger to see why it's not what you expect.  (You may get a different success code, such as `204`.)
2. Call your completion block with results instead of `nil`.

Comment: I set a break point to `if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200)` but it skips that part. It reads all the way to `*task =[self POST:@"/Accn" parameters:loginParameters`then it goes to return task and the else part in the view controller. I didn't understand what do you mean buy  "Call your completion block with results instead of nil."

Comment: Try disabling code optimization (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18472604/1445366).  I meant do something like `completion(responseObject, nil);` instead of `completion(nil, nil);`.

Comment: It seems like it is already disabled "None [-O0]". I changed the completion to what you said and it seems like it works just fine now. But I did not understand why that works because I am receiving 201 all the time.And if i use the same id i get 400 as "username exists". And in the next view I call one of my saved values from login info as `CredentialStore *credStore = [CredentialStore sharedStore];
    LoginInfo *loginInfo=credStore.loginInfo;
   self.exampleLabel.text = loginInfo.DeviceType;
 NSLog(@"this is the token %@",_exampleLabel.text);` and it shows the saved value. So how?