# NSUInteger in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, numbers, nsuinteger

I'm having a really weird problem here with NSUInteger in iOS7,

everything is perfect before iOS7, I guess it's related to the 64-bit support in iOS7.

My code is like this, very simple:

```
if (blah blah blah) {
    NSUInteger firstRow = 0;
    firstRow = ([self.types containsObject:self.selectedMajorType] ?
        [self.types indexOfObject:self.selectedMajorType] + 1 : 0);
    ...
}
```

According to my console,

[self.types containsObject:self.selectedMajorType] is **true**

[self.types indexOfObject:self.selectedMajorType]+1 is **1**,

no doubt, and indexOfObject also returns an NSUInteger (according to Apple's document),

here's the screenshot:
[image]
but firstRow is always f**king **0**

This is so creepy I don't know what's going on with NSUInteger,

can someone help me? Thanks a lot!!

____new finding____
[image]

I guess this is the problem? It's weird..

Comment: At what point in the execution do you print `firstRow`?

Comment: Hi, I printed these right after the code above

Comment: Are you sure it's not optimized out? Try printing everything using `NSLog` and not in the debugger.

Comment: Try to put parenthesis around ([self.types indexOfObject:self.selectedMajorType]+1) the problem might be due to precedence of operations

Comment: Hi @Dani, thanks for your comment! I used NSLog and it is 1 now. I guess it's optimized out. Could you please tell me more about the stuff? is it a feature of xcode? thanks!

Comment: @Eno: To ease debugging you can [turn off optimization in build settings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18472604/362589). This is a feature of the compiler Xcode is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to recreate this scenario but I was always getting the expected result 1.

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Here is the [project](https://space.zeo.net/g/2qio6), try running this and see if you still face the problem.

PS. I was using xcode 5.1 and iPhone 64bit Simulator.

=============**UPDATE**================

Here are some explanations on the lldb commands you used.

**po** : prints the objective C description of an object.

**print / p** : Evaluates a generalized expression in the current frame. Specify return type of the function if not used in your program.

Hope this screenshot will help you understand more.

[image]

Comment: Use `NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)firstRow);` , incase you get warnings/error.

Comment: Hi Aditya, thanks for your help, I've updated this question a little bit, it might give you new clues

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it turned out that I was using release scheme, so the debugging was optimized out. Haha,